# Field of generic type with getter that returns the right type?

Tags: java

Given the following two classes `Foo` and `FooBar`:

```
public abstract class Foo {
  private String type;
  private int id;

  public String getType() {...}
  public int getId() {...}
}

public class FooBar extends Foo {
  private String extraField;

  public String getExtraField() {...}
}
```

How do I implement a class with a field that could be either `Foo` or `FooBar`? For example, in the class `Example` below, I want the `getFoo()` method to return either an instance of `Foo` or an instance of `FooBar` such that all accessors are available:

```
public class Example {
  private Foo fooField;

  // Not correct!
  public Foo getFooField() {...}
}
```

I am thinking that I need to implement a generic class as a wrapper, but I'm not sure how to tie it into the `Example` class.

```
public interface FooWrapper<T extends Foo> {
  // Would I define some getter here?
  // Is this the right track?
}
```

**Update:** For clarification, `Example` does *not* extend `Foo`. `Example` is a completely different type that contains a field of type `Foo`/`FooBar`.

Comment: Is `FooWrapper` meant to be a decorator?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I suppose so. I'm very fuzzy on generics so it's just a thought for a potential solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your `Example` class generic like so:

```
class Example<T extends Foo> {
    private T fooField;
    public T getFooField() { return fooField;}
}
```

And then create parameterized instance, for `Foo` or `FooBar`:

```
Example<Foo> fooExample = new Example<Foo>();
Foo foo = fooExample.getFooField();
System.out.println(foo.getId());
System.out.println(foo.getType());

Example<FooBar> fooBarExample = new Example<FooBar>();
FooBar fooBar = fooBarExample.getFooField();
System.out.println(fooBar.getId());
System.out.println(fooBar.getType());
System.out.println(fooBar.getExtraField());
```

Comment: Well, that clearly answers my question. I just wish it solved my problem :-/